# Create "title" attribute using the text inside <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to take the text inside of an `<a>` tag and add it to `title` attribute of that tag using JavaScript?

For example:

```
<a href="#" title="">Hello</a>
```

I want the text "hello" to be the `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag. Like this:

```
<a href="#" title="Hello">Hello</a>
```

Can this be done with JavaScript? Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: @cookiemonster Well this is also tagged jQuery so you could post that API as well https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @NULL: True, but when the OP asks *"Can this be done with javascript?"*, I'd tend to assume that he needs to learn the basics first.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes :) I'm a beginner with javascript and this is a good start for me, thank you!

Comment: What possible purpose would this serve? Adding a `title` attribute that is a copy of the element content (apart from being rather trivial to implement) sounds so pointless that the real problem must be something else.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm adding 'title' attributes from the link's text so that when you hover the text shows in full. Currently I'm using css 'text-overflow'(ellipsis) for long link text. So, this helps display the entire text on rollover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, as requested:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i = 0;i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].title = anchors[i].textContent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spencerooni/z97rc/

Comment: Better `anchors[i].textContent || anchors[i].innerText`.

Comment: If this is just for links, the OP could use `document.links` instead to narrow the set.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I didn't know that existed. Learn something new every day... :)

Comment: I would be using this for links and images.

Comment: @Zenko: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href], img");` but an `<img>` doesn't have any content like an `<a>` element.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ID for the specific tag (e.g. `<a href="#" id="atag">...</a>`):

```
$('#atag').attr('title', $('#atag').text());
```

or if you'd like to do this for all `a` tags:

```
$('a').each(
  function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pY7Vp/2/)

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this); /* slight optimisation over using $(this) twice */
   $this.attr('title',$this.text()); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most simple jQuery form:

```
$('a').attr('title', function(){ return $(this).text() })
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4xwkv/)**